# Rear Window Terminology

Tags: power-windows

Context \ Goal: search a .pdf file.  Correct search keyword needed to target mechanic's repair information.

1995 Integra LS 4-door backseat passenger side **window**.   What is the proper / best search term?  I need to differentiate between the four door power-windows that roll up and down and the static rear glass (windshield counterpart).

The rear passenger-side door power-window is very loose and travels beyond the normal upper limit.  Seeking any advice regarding how to diagnose and correct.

What is the name of said window?  Thank you

Comment: What kind of vehicle? Give us the year/make/model of the vehicle ... some manufacturers may call these static windows something different. Conversely, just ask your question and let us know the information you need. Someone on here may surprise you ;-)

Comment: A "quarterlight" can or has been used... depends on location, make etc...

Answer (score 1):

My Subaru manual describes the glass in the rear doors as Rear Door Glass for the portion that moves and Partition Glass as the static piece.